# Remove all item of Model using Emberjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, model, ember.js

Define Model

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
   revision: 12,
   adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter
});

App.Markets = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr("string"),
    created: DS.attr("string")
});

App.Markets.FIXTURES = [
    {id:1, name:"name1", created:'2013-1-1'},
    {id:2, name:"name2", created:'2013-1-2'},
    {id:3, name:"name3", created:'2013-1-3'}
];
```

Define Controller

```
App.MarketsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    changeMarkets:function(marketer_id){
        // remove all item of App.Markets Model
        //-------

        // add new item in App.Markets Model
        App.Sources.createRecord({
            id: 100,
            name: "new name1",
            created: "2014-2-1"
        });

        App.Sources.createRecord({
            id: 200,
            name: "new name2",
            created: "2014-2-2"
        });

        App.Sources.createRecord({
            id: 300,
            name: "new name3",
            created: "2014-2-3"
        });
    }   
});
```

I am going to remove all itme and add some one to model object in changeMarkets function using emberjs.
I'd like to know how to remove all itme of Model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The short** see here for a working example: http://jsbin.com/eyojit/5/edit

**The long:** To remove all the items from the controller `content` property you could use the built-in method `clear()`, this will be more performant and your bindings will work correctly. Then to set new items you could do it like this, here the relevant code:

```
App.MarketsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  changeMarkets:function(marketer_id){
    // remove all item of App.Markets Model
    this.get('content').clear();

    // add new item in App.Markets Model
    this.set('content', [
      App.Markets.createRecord({
        id: 100,
        name: "new name1",
        created: "2014-2-1"
      }),
      App.Markets.createRecord({
        id: 200,
        name: "new name2",
        created: "2014-2-2"
      }),
      App.Markets.createRecord({
        id: 300,
        name: "new name3",
        created: "2014-2-3"
      })
    ]);
  }   
});
```

Hope it helps.